# Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I recently installed Tensorflow-gpu and 2 errors popped up.

> Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
> Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

Thing is I want to use my GPU so I am not sure if this will affect it.

I installed cudnn yet still nothing. I installed VS code 2017 and installed c++ with it yet I still get this error. I am using pycharm as my interpreter.

Comment: Please follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) link and verify that you have followed all the steps to enable GPU setup in your system by fulfilling the mentioned hardware/software requirements. Let us know a few other details (like which `OS` you are using, installed `python / tensorflow` version along with the steps followed to install tensorflow) if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a driver issue wherein TF is not being able to detect your GPU .

Follow these steps to get it resolved :

1. Install latest Python :

   sudo apt install python3
2. python3 --version

   Set Directory / Continue in the root folder.
3. Instal Latest NVIDIA drivers from [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html) (I used Ubuntu LTS)
4. Install Cuda Toolkit (Use NVIDIA account / You will need to create a
   new account)
5. Install CuDNN from[here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download).

You can refer to a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75276170/conda-cannot-see-cuda-version/77328828#77328828)