# Conda cannot see Cuda version

Tags: python, tensorflow, cudnn

I am trying to install the newest Tensorflow GPU version to an Ubuntu environment. The Cuda drivers are correctly installed and working, which I can confirm with the following commands:

```
nvcc --version
```

With output:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_May__3_18:49:52_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0
```

Also, `nvidia-smi` returns a valid result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.43.04    Driver Version: 515.43.04    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    68W / 300W |   9712MiB / 16384MiB |      7%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

It seems I have the Cuda Version 11.7. Creating an empty Conda environment for Python 3.9, I want to install cudatoolkit and cudnn as instructed at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=en:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
```

However it complains that I do not have the correct Cuda version and won't install:

```
 - cudatoolkit=11.2 -> __cuda[version='>=11.2.1|>=11|>=11.2|>=11.2.2']

 Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.7
```

Obviously, my Cuda version meets the requirements, but somehow Conda would not see it. This seems to be a rare error, I didn't saw many similar issues on my search and turned to here. What can be wrong here?

Comment: No, nvidia-smi does not show the installed CUDA version, it shows the highest CUDA version that the driver supports.

Comment: Could you try again by uninstalling the CUDA 11.7 then reinstalling the CUDA using `conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0`. Let us know if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

The whole Tensorflow environment setup thing is very much taxing and less user friendly.

Every step needs to be carefully evaluated otherwise there can be version mismatches

There is an option in the GCP marketplace to have it run on a VM with all dependencies pre-installed, but again it is not free.

Given the recent project I came across wherein I had to setup Tensorflow in Ubuntu (22.x) , I came across a lot of difficulties just to find the correct way to do it.

Here are the steps :

1. Open the Command Line and update System's repository list :

   sudo apt update
2. Install latest Python :

   sudo apt install python3

   python3 --version
3. Set Directory / Continue in the root folder.
4. Instal Latest NVIDIA drivers from [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html) (I used Ubuntu LTS)
5. Install Cuda Toolkit (Use NVIDIA account / You will need to create a new account)
6. Install CuDNN from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download). ( wget < link > )