# Gpu environment setup Failure

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu

My lap is Dell g15 with nvidia rtx 3060. Help me to run gpu on the jupyter. I am trying to install, but failed to setup gpu environment.

I followed this https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip.

I followed the steps in this link https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip, but failed.

After using the python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))" ]. o gpu devices are returned. can anyone help me. thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @KAKUTURU THRUSHWANTH, Did you follow all the mentioned steps by steps instructions in the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system_requirements) and set the path for the required software(Nvidia, CUDA, cuDNN) to have GPU Support enabled in your system? Let us know with some more details of your system OS and configuration if the issue still persists. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comprehensive guide of how you can correctly make Tensorflow detect your GPU and use it successfully in the code !

Follow these steps and let me know if you still face the issue :

1. Install latest Python :

   sudo apt install python3

   python3 --version
2. Set Directory / Continue in the root folder.
3. Instal Latest NVIDIA drivers from [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html) (I used Ubuntu LTS)
4. Install Cuda Toolkit (Use NVIDIA account / You will need to create a new account)
5. Install CuDNN from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download).

You can refer to my similar issue answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75276170/conda-cannot-see-cuda-version/77328828#77328828).

Getting the correct versions of Python-Tensorflow-Ubuntu-Cuda-CuDnn is the key to successfully running GPU intensive tasks on your machine.