# Using GPU for TensorFlow in VSC

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, compatibility

I've just upgraded my Windows by 11th version and struggling to force TensorFlow to use GPU in Visual studio code.

So I have several questions:

1. Is it possible to make it on Windows 11, or should I downgrade it to version 10?
2. For this purposes is it better to use Anaconda's python, or Py, downloaded from the website?
3. Is it possible to make it with VSC, or should I download Visual Studio?

I tried everything except right compatible versions of all the software (CUDA, Nvidia drivers, cuDNN: I downloaded the newest version of them).
I have GeForce RTX3050 Laptop, Win11.

Comment: This is too vague, you are probably overlooking the issue, need to provide a lot more details, to start, which version of TensorFlow?

Comment: My TensorFlow version is 2.13.1. My Python is 3.11.5, and all supplemental software is the newest version.

Comment: Are you using TensorFlow inside WSL? If not, that is the problem, as TensorFlow does not natively support GPUs in Windows since version 2.10, see https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, it depends on the version of Tensorflow as after TF 2.10.

> TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on
> native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to
> install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow or tensorflow-cpu
> and, optionally, try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin

Here is the [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) for that.

Secondly, I'd suggest to use a separate virtual environment and use pip for the matter. Anaconda may bring additional complications.

For GPU usage, you can refer to my similar answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76519424/gpu-environment-setup-failure/77373240#77373240).

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer! I've downloaded Tf-GPU via WSL2, but I faced anther problem: while working with deep models, my GPU runs out of memory. Do you have any suggestions how to tarkle this problem. Like is it possible to allocate some RAM for such purpose?